# Django force download file on redirect instead of showing content

Tags: django

Right now I have a download button which when clicked redirects to the page with the file and shows it content. I don't want it to do that. I want it to forcefully download the content to the users device instead of showing it. How do I do that?

My current code:

```
def download_item(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Usertasks, pk=pk)
    output_path = item.OutputPath
    filename = item.TaskID + "_" + item.TaskNavn + "." + item.Taskformat
    if request.user.id == item.user_id:
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Type']= 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = output_path
        return response 
    if not request.user.id == item.user_id:
        return redirect('/account/login/')
```

Comment: 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename) must be Content-Disposition, not Content-Type.

Comment: @lampslave That fixed it! If you want to you can post this as an answer and i'll mark it correct.